# iOS textFieldShouldReturn not running

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

I've created this in my .h:

```
@interface Class : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate
```

And then in my .m:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {    
if (textField == username) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}else if (textField == password) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
return YES;
}
```

but when i try to run some code inside either the if for username or password it never gets run. I've tried to debug it, but when i tap on my text field it just opens the keyboard and it's not debugging. So it seems like textFieldShouldReturn never gets run, why?

Any help is much appreciated.

SOLUTION: Add:
    username.delegate = password.delegate = self; in your .m file

Comment: set `delegate` for your textField?

Comment: What are the type of username and password ?

Comment: did you set delegate to the `username or password` field.?

Comment: each textfield must have delegate to use textfieldshould return.and its called when you press on return key not when you start the typing in it

Comment: Please could you mention what do you want to do with username and password field and why are you writing this (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField method?

Comment: I'm missing the delegates for username and password, how to set them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of textFieldShouldReturn: method is to determine if the text field should process the pressing of the return button on [virtual] keyboard.

I assume you are looking for textFieldShouldEndEditing: delegate method.

PS. I assume you have set password.delegate = username.delegate = self;

Comment: No i miss the delegates for each field, can i just set them in my viewDidLoad? and how?

Comment: thx after adding username.delegate = self;
    password.delegate = self; in viewDidLoad I'm now able to debug

Comment: You may even write in a single-line "set": password.delegate = username.delegate = self;

Comment: Why is it possible?^^, wont username:delegate override password.delegate then?

Comment: This syntax just sets "self" to items mentioned on the left. It's equal to yours 2 separate sets.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be called by tapping the text field, This will only get called when you hit the return key on the keyboard. Be sure you've set the delegate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This function is called when you hit return key on the keyboard and not when you touch the textfield

The function called when you touch the textfield is

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
if (textField == username) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}else if (textField == password) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even try to set delegate for both username and password textfield from the xib/storyboard by connecting the outlet-delegate to the file owner. that may solve your problem.